# Make line chart take full width of parent using mpchart?

Tags: android, charts, linechart, mpandroidchart

I've customized a line chart which looks just about what I wanted. But I'm unable to remove the padding from it left after switching off the axis lables and lines. Setting

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

has helped but it did not remove the padding completely. In short what I want is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Android Studio's generated activity which had padding in the outermost layout.

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

It worked perfectly after removing parent padding. It might be a silly question for experienced developers, but for a newbie like me it took a while to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();    
leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
rightAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
```

**Hope, this answer will solve you problem.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dhruv, but I've already tried this but it did not work.